# Microsoft SQL Server : attach database with FILESTREAM from new location fails, because location not available

Tags: sql-server, database, filestream

You just providing new `.mdf` file location, everything goes perfect, but... error and database not attached.

It occurs ALWAYS, when you attaching `.mdf`'s from different versions of Microsoft SQL Server.

What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple :

1. Just  go to error message, find missed location of your FILESTREAM directory (yes, it was not recognized automatically, even it is near the mdf file).
2. Create location (directory) manually.
3. Move you FILESTREAM directory content to it.
4. Enable permissions (sometimes people just add "Full" for all, but it is not recommended) on new location for Microsoft SQL Server (yes, it was not done by default).

Now, try to attach your database again. It must success.

Good luck